# How do get change value of <input> element?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a input in datalist

```
<input type="text" value="1" id="txtcount">
```

I want get new value of it when text change.

I use this code but don't work for me .

```
<script>
//look no global needed:)

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get the initial value
   var $el = $('#txtcount');
   $el.data('oldVal',  $el.val() );


   $el.change(function(){
        //store new value
        var $this = $(this);
        var newValue = $this.data('newVal', $this.val());
   })
   .focus(function(){
        // Get the value when input gains focus
        var oldValue = $(this).data('oldVal');
   });
});
```

Comment: What *does not work*? AFAIK, `change` happens when you lose focus of the input.

Comment: No , I use a alert() in change but don' work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
$('#txtcount').keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var message =  $('#txtcount').val();
    alert(message);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
});
```

or you can get the the value on "onTextChanged" event of TextField

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
$('#txtcount').change(function() { ... });
```

or this

```
$("#txtcount").keypress(function() { .......});
```

or this

```
$('#txtcount').keyup(function() {..........});
```